# magento random products order and remembering the order

Tags: php, sql, magento, zend-framework

i have a trouble figuring this out. i'm trying to get a list of random products like so :

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status',1)
                ->addCategoryFilter($category)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility',array('in' => Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH))
                ->setPageSize(20)
                ->setCurPage($page);
$products->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RAND()'));
```

this code works fine but what i need is to remember the order so can go through the pages with ajax calls.

is there a way to make this randomness controlled by maybe some sort of a number that if given will always return the same order of rows ?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions that may suit your needs.

The first would be to order by a CRC32 of one of the unique product fields (e.g. product ID). It may be worth adding a new column to the table to make this faster instead of working out the CRC32 of the field for each row every time you select.

The second suggestion would be to add a new column in which you put a randomly generated number for each row in the table.